# Is it possible to append laravel DB queries?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**CODES IN CONTROLLER**

```
public function getAthleteProperties(Request $request)
{
    $getAthlete = DB::table('students')
                ->join('sports', 'students.id', '=', 'sports.athlete');
                ->select('students.*', 'sports.*')
                ->get();

    if($request->input('gender') == 1)
    {
        //add this line of queries to $getAthlete queries
        ->where('gender', "m");
    }
    else
        ->where('gender', "f");

    if($request->input('active') == 1)
    {
        //add this line of queries to $getAthlete queries
        ->where('active', "y");
    }
    else
        ->where('active', "n");

    return view('admin', compact('getAthlete'));
}
```

Is it possible to append queries in laravel? For example I have codes as shown on above codes, if the condition for gender is 1 and active is 1 then in the end of the $getAthlete queries will become like this. Is it possible? How?

```
    $getAthlete = DB::table('students')
                ->join('sports', 'students.id', '=', 'sports.athlete');
                ->select('students.*', 'sports.*')
                ->where('gender', "m") //added because condition is true
                ->where('active', "y") //added because condition is true
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to use the "get" method at first, since it executes the select statement.

```
public function getAthleteProperties(Request $request)
{
    $getAthlete = DB::table('students')
                ->join('sports', 'students.id', '=', 'sports.athlete')
                ->select('students.*', 'sports.*');

    if($request->input('gender') == 1) {
        //add this line of queries to $getAthlete queries
        $getAthlete->where('gender', 'm');
    } else {
        $getAthlete->where('gender', 'f');
    }

    if($request->input('active') == 1) {
        //add this line of queries to $getAthlete queries
        $getAthlete->where('active', 'y');
    } else {
        $getAthlete->where('active', 'n');
    }
    $getAthlete = $getAthlete->get();

    return view('admin', compact('getAthlete'));
}
```

**UPDATE:**

With the latest versions of laravel a [conditional clause](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses) method was introduced. So we can do it this way:

```
$getAthlete = DB::table('students')
    ->join('sports', 'students.id', '=', 'sports.athlete')
    ->select('students.*', 'sports.*')
    ->when($request->input('gender') == 1, function ($query) {
        return $query->where('gender', 'm');
    }, function ($query) {
        return $query->where('gender', 'f');
    })
    ->when($request->input('active') == 1, function ($query) {
        return $query->where('active', 'y');
    }, function ($query) {
        return $query->where('active', 'n');
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: I got "A non-numeric value encountered" error in my views. But if I put the queries together, it runs normally. Why?

Comment: Im sorry, i didnt notice this line `$getAthlete = $getAthlete->get();` I put `$getAthlete->get()` without the equal